# MobaXterm Network error: Connection refused while trying to duplicate a Tab

Tags: mobaxterm

I am using MobaXterm 20.6 to launch WSl2. When I right click on a tab and select duplicate tab, I get the error message

Network error: Connection refused

I do not get the message if I start the new tab by double clicking on any entry in the user sessions menu on the left side of the window.
I do not see this error with previous versions of MobaXterm.
Thanks for any hint.
G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed in version V21.0 Preview 3 Build 4592.
G